# How add class to parent in angular application?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-components

I have next HTML

```
// This is parent
<div class="some-class">
     // This is child
     <totalizer</totalizer>
</div>
```

How can I change parents style ( add new class ) from child?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an `EventEmitter` `@Output()` property that signals the parent component to add/remove a `css` class dynamically using `ngClass`.

In your child `totalizer` component, define,

```
@Output() cssRefresh = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

//when you need to add/remove css emit an event out to the parent like this 
// (preferably in a method in this component),

this.cssRefresh.emit(true); // or 'false' depending on add/remove
```

Then in the parent `html` modify this,

```
<div class="some-class" [ngClass]="{ 'dynamicClass1 dynamicClass2 dynamicClass3': addCss}">
     // This is child
     <totalizer (cssRefresh)=refreshCss($event)></totalizer>
</div>
```

Inside your parent component add this method and property,

```
addCss = false; // set 'initial state' based on your needs

refreshCss(add: boolean) {
 this.addCss = add ? true : false;
}
```

More on `ngClass` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).