# NgClassForParent based on standard NgClass Angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

I'm currently struggling with some very specific (detailed and dynamic) form, that uses a lot of custom made components with semantic-ui as CSS library.

I know that I can use `ngClass` to style inside my component. But, since it's a validation, i would like to add `error` class to the parent DOM element. I tried developing an extension of `NgClass` without any luck. My idea was to intercept `ElementRef` and give `NgClass` the one from the parent.

Maybe I'm doing this the wrong way, that's why i'm asking. What the best way to accomplish this task? Is it even possible?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241587/1098814) but it require to add one event handle for each component! It doesn't feel right.

Comment: This is wrong way of thinking of things. Children components can't access parents without their consent. There's no idiomatic way to do this, unless you pass element reference to a child through an input . The cited answer shows a viable approach to do this. This depends on what you're trying to achieve. E.g. there may be involved a service that acts as event bus; still, parent component is responsible for changing its own class.

Comment: Interesting... Maybe I should be thinking on adding some logic in parent element... a directive that read the `Child` control state?

Comment: Possibly. It depends on your form. Is it reactive? Angular reactive forms naturally provide a way to handle this. Top-level FormGroup (i.e. <form>) is aware of all changes in children, then changes can be propagated to parents.

Comment: Due to its complexity, I lean toward template based form, so yes, there is a `<form` element wrapping all... i'm working with `formGroups`, i'm working on that directive right now.